# Sphinx indexer delta --rotate

Tags: linux, sphinx

I have followed the sphinx manual here:  http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#delta-updates on how to perform delta updates to your index.

my searchd is running of the correct config file.
the indexer was previously ran to create the main index.

when I run this command:

```
indexer -c /home/brandon/workspace/gallery/server/lib/sphinx/sphinx.conf --rotate delta
```

I get this result:

```
using config file '/home/brandon/workspace/gallery/server/lib/sphinx/sphinx.conf'...
read 0.1 of 0.1 MB, 100.0% done
merged 10.8 Kwords
merged in 0.010 sec
total 389 reads, 0.000 sec, 2.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 7 writes, 0.000 sec, 78.6 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
rotating indices: succesfully sent SIGHUP to searchd (pid=28039).
```

Everything looks as though it worked, and the main index should have been updated.  I then go to my search bar, but it has not been updated as I can't search for the new item.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you search using *both* (main and delta) indexes in your app. 
Delta index is just another index, so basically when you reindex delta index, it adds nothing to the main index. So your app should search in both indexes (main, delta).

Comment: Excellent.  That seemed to be my issue.

Comment: Or you can merge the delta index into the main index, which is what I think most people do.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is simple.
Write a simple program to index it frequently and after that restart sphinx service ( searchd ).
The results would come out.

Make sure you include both main and index in the api code. ( $index = "main,delta"; )

you may follow my instruction in the previous answer here: [Does Sphinx auto update is index when you add data to your SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576489/does-sphinx-auto-update-is-index-when-you-add-data-to-your-sql)

Comment: No, DONT restart searchd. That is wasteful and will cause downtime. the --rotate, will do all that is required to load the new index. (it does this by telling searchd to reload the required index. It happens seamlessly)